# Helping with void *__ctx[] CRYPTO_MINALIGN_ATTR in struct aead_request (Crypto Subsystem in Linux Kernel)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm a newbie in Linux driver. Now, I am testing my Linux crypto driver. However, I have some kernel crash bug related to this pointer array. In my opinion, this pointer array is related to a Variable Length Array In Struct (VLAIS). I did some research about how `void *__ctx[] CRYPTO_MINALIGN_ATTR` work but still didn't understand. Can anyone help me clarify this type and how it work? Thank in advance.

This is the location of this type (*include/crypto/aead.h*):

```c
struct aead_request {
    struct crypto_async_request base;
    unsigned int assoclen;
    unsigned int cryptlen;
    u8 *iv;
    struct scatterlist *src;
    struct scatterlist *dst;
    void *__ctx[] CRYPTO_MINALIGN_ATTR;
};
```

Comment: It's not VLA. It's a placeholder for an array to be allocated in one chunk with the header. So somebody does `ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct) + sizeof(elem) * nelements);` to get it. Macro is used to force alignment of the `ctx` member and does not affect the rest.

Comment: `void *` seems wrong.  Why is the type not specified?

Comment: I don't think it is actually being used as an array of `void *`. It's just a placeholder for a possibly zero length chunk of data appended to the structure. Using the `__ctx` member in an expression will produce a `void **` pointer that can be converted to a `void *` by simple pointer conversion (not by dereferencing), pointing to itself (i.e. pointing to the start of the chunk of data).

Comment: @stark not at all. See what Ian commented.

Comment: Variable-sized structures are common in the kernel, but are generally a 0-length array with a type, not a void*.  Example: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/include/drm/bridge/mhl.h#L333